# Angular Material transform table to boxes on small screens

Tags: html, angularjs, html-table, angular-material

I have an AngularJS website with the Angular Material design. On one screen I have a table and right there is my problem, because tables in Material design aren't really responsive.

My question: Is it possible to show the normal table on big screens and transform the table information from single lines to a box-like layout when the page is displayed on smaller screens? Something like this:

```
Name   |   City   |   Gender
------------------------------
Alice  |   NY     |   f
Bob    |   LA     |   m
```

This table on big screens. And the following design on smaller screens.

```
Name   Alice
City   NY
Gender f
-------------
Name   Bob
City   LA
Gender m
```

I am aware of the layout options with the screen sizes (xs, sm, ...).

I tried to show tables based on this code on smaller screens, but then all the information are in a single line. And not one line for every attribute.

```
<tr md-row ng-repeat="person in persons">
  <th md-cell>Name</th>
  <td md-cell>{{person.name}}</td>
  <th md-cell>State</th>
  <td md-cell>{{person.state}}</td>
  <th md-cell>Gender</th>                   
  <td md-cell>{{person.gender}}</td>
</tr>
```

Result:

```
Name Alice City NY Gender f
...
```

Is there any good solution for my problem? Or another approach I am not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/mEzJKG?editors=1010#0)

This solution is flexible to allow for changes to user information.

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp" layout-fill>
  <div ng-if="showRow">
    <div ng-repeat="user in users">
      <div ng-if="$first">
        <div layout="row">
          <span flex ng-repeat="(key, value) in users[0]">
            {{key}}
          </span>
        </div>
        <md-divider></md-divider>
      </div>
      <div layout="row">
        <span flex ng-repeat="(key, value) in user">
          {{value}}
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div display="column" ng-if="showColumn">
    <div ng-repeat="user in users">
      <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in user" layout="row">
        <span flex>{{key}}</span>
        <span flex>{{value}}</span>
      </div>
      <md-divider></md-divider>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $mdMedia, $window) {
  $scope.users = [
    {Name: "Alice", City: "NY", Gender: "f"},
    {Name: "Bob", City: "LA", Gender: "m"}
  ];
  $scope.showColumn = false;
  $scope.showRow = true;

  display();

  angular.element($window).bind("resize", function() {
    display();
    $scope.$apply();
  });

  function display () {
     if ($mdMedia("gt-xs")) {
        $scope.showColumn = false;
        $scope.showRow = true;
      }
      else if ($mdMedia("xs")) {
        $scope.showColumn = true;
        $scope.showRow = false;
      }
  }
});
```

Comment: I like your solution because it is very flexible about the actual content. The layout should be the other way round (rows and columns), but that is no big deal. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can do it using a table, but the material library offers very powerful features with flexbox that does allow for the responsive layout that you are describing. Seemed like an interesting problem so I had a go at doing a plunkr.

The html below will adjust the layout and display / hide various labels to achieve the result you want. Try changing the size of your browser when viewing the plunkr, there is a breakpoint that will switch the views.

```
<div layout="row" flex hide show-gt-md>
  <div flex="20">Name</div>
  <div flex="20">City</div>
  <div flex="20">Gender</div>
</div>
<div ng-repeat="p in data" layout-gt-md="row" layout="column">
  <div flex="20" layout="row">
    <div flex="30" hide-gt-md>Name</div>
    {{p.name}}
  </div>
  <div flex="20" layout="row">
    <div flex="30" hide-gt-md>City</div>
    {{p.city}}
  </div>
  <div flex="20" layout="row">
    <div flex="30" hide-gt-md>Gender</div>
    {{p.gender}}
    </div>
</div>
```

https://plnkr.co/rvgwYMjlFazvM4SXyOtC

Comment: That does exactly what I want it to do. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add a TR to the TD tags.

```
<tr md-row ng-repeat="person in persons">
      <th md-cell>Name</th>
      <td md-cell>
          <tr>{{person.name}}</tr>
      </td>
      <th md-cell>State</th>
      <td md-cell>{{person.state}}</td>
      <th md-cell>Gender</th>
      <td md-cell>{{person.gender}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: That doesn't work. But you brought me to the idea to use multiple tables. With `<table ng-repeat="person in persons">` it does exactly what I want it to do. There are now multiple tables instead of one, but that isn't a problem. It is even better, because I can place two tables side by side if there is enough place on the screen. So thank you very much :)